# c# sql wildcard not working

Tags: c#, mysql, querying

I am attempting to use "%" in order to search for a range of dates. In the table the dates are of the format "03/01/2015" and I am trying to return data for all dates of a specific month (03/2015 for example).

I am creating two strings of the format...

```
String datePrev1 = monthLast + "%";
String datePrev2 = "%" + yearLast;
```

Where datePrev1 == "03%" and datePrev2 == "%2015" which I have confirmed to be generating correctly.

My SQL search method is...

```
    SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT project, prevWeekHours FROM submissionsHours WHERE (WWID = '" + ID + "' AND (datePrevWeek LIKE '" + datePrev1 + "' AND datePrevWeek LIKE '" + datePrev2 + "'))", Conn1);

    Conn1.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
    int totalTime = 0;
    while (reader.Read() == true)
    {
        project.Add(reader[0].ToString());
        projTime.Add(Convert.ToInt32(reader[1]));
        totalTime += Convert.ToInt32(reader[1]);
    }
    Conn1.Close();
    int index = project.Count; //total amount of projects 
    testLabel.Text = index.ToString() + "..." + datePrev1+datePrev2;
```

The testLabel.Text I have for troubleshooting is returning 0 for the index indicating there were no matches for this string when there are certainly entries in the table that should match it.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

I have attempted querying like...

```
... WHERE datePrevWeek LIKE '03/__/2015';
... WHERE datePrevWeek LIKE '03____2015';
```

To no success... Thanks.

Comment: Dont store dates as Varchar's store them as DateTime's

Comment: Have you tried just running your expected SQL Query to ensure this returns results? Also have you tried profiling this when it is running to check the output of your SQL query?

Comment: Use parameters your SQL is exposed to SQL injection.

Comment: Can you show us the definition for your table.  You are querying the column as if it is a varchar, but if it is a `DateTime` then you need to use date functions to do what you want.

Comment: I AM currently using Varchar to store the dates - I know I should and probably will update it to DateTime this is someone else's old code I was tasked with.

At this point I just want to see what the solution to this is for strings in general as it is still an issue that can come up in another format.

Comment: Have you tried `datePrevWeek Like '03%2015'`?

Comment: Also is `WWID` a varchar and have you tried removing the `..WWID = '" + ID + "'...` to see if you get any results?

Comment: Have you tried *datePrevWeek between '03/01/2015' and '03/31/2015'*

Comment: @juharr  
The WWID query WAS preventing it! I have no idea why... I have many similar queries with WWID... Yes WWID is also VARCHAR type.

Comment: @minersrevolt Maybe there isn't a record where the ID and date match?  Or the ID just doesn't match.  Just check the value of ID and the data in your table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT project, prevWeekHours 
FROM submissionsHours 
WHERE WWID = @ID 
AND (YEAR(datePrevWeek)*100)+MONTH(datePrevWeek) = @YEARMONTH
```

`@YEARMONTH` should be of format 201503 representing march 2015.

Using parameters will avoid sql injection.

When `datePrevWeek` is varchar

```
 SELECT project, prevWeekHours 
        FROM submissionsHours 
        WHERE WWID = @ID 
        AND right(datePrevWeek,7) = @YEARMONTH_STR
```

@YEARMONTH_STR is of format '01/2015'

Comment: I attempted this as:       

 `SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT project, prevWeekHours FROM submissionsHours WHERE (WWID = '" + ID + "' AND right(datePrevWeek,7) =  '03/2015')", Conn1);`      

Still no dice. Same problem as before returning no matches.

Comment: If you have access to database, try executing without where condition and check  whether your where condition's data is present in the result.

Answer (score 0):

Once you store dates in the format '2015-03-13',...

Plan A: `WHERE dt LIKE '2015%'`

Plan B (This is more efficient, given a suitable index):

```
WHERE dt >= CONCAT('2015', '-01-01') 
  AND dt <  CONCAT('2015', '-01-01') + INTERVAL 1 YEAR
```

(I'm assuming `'2015'` is filled in by the code.)

Answer (score -1):

Try Below:

Declare @Dat Date

set @Dat = '03/01/2015'

SELECT CAST(MONTH(@Dat) AS VARCHAR(2)) + '/' + CAST(YEAR(@Dat) AS VARCHAR(4)) AS [DD/YYYY]